# Get only closed questions from the Stack Exchange api, via /questions?

Tags: stackexchange-api, stackexchange

I want to get only closed questions from `/questions` of the Stack Exchange API.

I've played around a bit with the filters, and I've come up with [something which gives](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!*7Pmg84vZ4DiDS2g1yshkLV6zTe8&site=stackoverflow&run=true) me some JSON like this for each question:

```
{
      "tags": [
        "c++",
        "opencl",
        "intel"
      ],
      "close_vote_count": 0,
      "title": "Weird OpenCL calls side effect on C++ for loop performance",
      "body": "<p>I'm working on a C++ project using OpenCL. I'm using the CPU as an OpenCL device with the  <a href=\"http://registrationcenter.intel.com/irc_nas/5193/intel_code_builder_for_opencl_2015_ubuntu_5.0.0.43_x64.tgz\" rel=\"nofollow\">intel OpenCL runtime</a></p>[...]"
    },
```

**Now, I want only questions which are closed.**

How can I do this ?

(another thing: How could I *exclude* closed questions from the results ?)

Comment: How is this question related to Java?

Comment: Do questions closed as a duplicate using a dupehammer show up as having 5 close votes still?

Comment: @JamesThorpe, I suppose they don't, I edited my question. The point is that I only want closed questions, no matter how many close voted there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this by using the following query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Posts
WHERE ClosedDate IS NOT NULL
```

This however does not tell you the reason for the closure, to obtain this you should look into the `PostHistoryTable` which contains detailed information on all changes related to a post.

Comment: I want to do this via the API, and not through the data explorer, which kind of hard to use as a data source for an app. But thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: I'm not aware on how to get the count value while using the API, but you could use https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&closed=True&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true to get all closed questions. Perhaps that helps?

Comment: I have done this using the advanced search, as per your link.  Thanks for your answer, as I did kind of do it with a combination of SEDE and the Advanced Search api in the end.